# PHP returning PDOException 'could not find driver' when trying to connect do SQLite3

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to connect a SQLite Database using PDO, but i am getting this error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

In my code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:remedios.sqlite');
```

Also, the command `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` lists only mysql.
I am using a Ubuntu 14.04

But the problem is that I already installed pdo_sqlite (installed with `apt-get sqlite3 php5-sqlite`).
I also checked it on:

- My phpinfo() shows sqlite3 (phpinfo is here: [PHPInfo](http://bivissoft.com/receituario/api/info.php))
- I have `extension=pdo_sqlite.so` in my PHP configuration file in   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini (phpinfo lists this file in "Additional .ini files parsed")
- I have pdo_sqlite.so in folder `/usr/lib/php5/20121212`
- Already tried to reinstall sqlite3, php5, php5-sqlite

### Edit

Configurations files below:

**20-pdo_sqlite.ini**

```
; configuration for php SQLite module
; priority=20
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
```

**20-sqlite3.ini**

```
; configuration for php SQLite module
; priority=20
extension=sqlite3.so
```

### Edit2

Find this error on apache error.log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Nov 13 00:03:42.704671 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1938] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Nov 13 00:03:42.704702 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1938] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini and /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini ?

Comment: Edited my question including configurations. Also checked that I have sqlite3.so in /usr/lib/php5/20121212 folder

Comment: Any relevant messages in the Apache error log?

Comment: And for the sake of completeness - stop and start Apache, and see if the problem is still reproducing.

Comment: Nice! Found an error on apache error log. Edited the question including it. But I didnt find solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the SQLite client library, I think the package is libsqlite3-0 on Ubuntu:

`apt-get install libsqlite3-0`

restart Apache after that.

UPDATE - we figured it out in the chat with the help of `ldconfig -p | grep sqlite`. It found a stale installation of libsqlite3 in /usr/local/lib that was conflicting with the one that Apache was using. Removing the conflicting installation, and re-installing sqlite3 packages solved the problem.

Comment: It already installed. Tried to remove and install again, but still the same error

Comment: `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 | grep sqlite3_column_table_name` is it there?   And have you really restarted Apache, if it is?

Comment: this command brings me: `sqlite3_column_table_name` and `sqlite3_column_table_name16` as result. Also restarted Apache, and got the same error on error.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94998/discussion-between-sasha-pachev-and-bivis).

Comment: `ldconfig -p | grep sqlite` worked! After restarted Apache, the issue has been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: dash should be dot ``apt-get install libsqlite3.0``

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem and I think it is important to give another elaborate answer on this. The root of the problem was that I built my own newest version of sqlite from sources (repo for Ubuntu 16.04 is outdated) without `SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA` definition. It worked before I restarted the machine. Probably it's the previous version was running or something like that, because after a reboot I've got the trouble.

http://source.online.free.fr/Linux_HowToCompileSQLite.html

> The SQLitePass library uses specific SQLite functions to retrieve schema information on an SQL statement.
>
> These functions are :
>
> ```
>     sqlite3_column_database_name
>     sqlite3_column_database_name16
>     sqlite3_column_table_name
>     sqlite3_column_table_name16
>     sqlite3_column_origin_name
>     sqlite3_column_origin_name16
>     sqlite3_table_column_metadata
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, they are not always available in the precompiled library available on the SQLite webpage or in the sqlite package dedicated to your Linux distribution.
>
> In order to get these functions in our sqlite3.so library, we need to compile the SQLite source code with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA] compiler directive.

That's why `less +G /var/log/php_errors.log` output had the line

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name in Unknown on line 0

although the `pdo_sqlite` was present in `phpinfo();` output all the time.

To solve the problem I did follow the compilation instructions by the link above: open `sqlite3.c` in the sources and after the lines

```
#define SQLITE_CORE 1
#define SQLITE_AMALGAMATION 1
#ifndef SQLITE_PRIVATE
# define SQLITE_PRIVATE static
#endif
```

add

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
```

then run

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
make: Nothing to be done for 'check'.
$ sudo make install
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

and now sqlite is working again.

Answer (score 0):

type this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```